# Как правильно запускать python тесты в AltUnity Tester?

Tags: python, unity3d, test-automation

У меня есть готовые тесты на python и проект-образец.
Мне нужно запустить проект и тесты в AltUnity Tester. Я ознакомился с документацией и запустил проект в AltUnity Tester (run in editor). Далее, мне нужно отдельно запустить файл с тестом?
Я совсем новичок во всем этом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Видимо, вы не совсем ознакомились с документацией, потому что там все описывается по пунктам: [ссылка](https://altom.gitlab.io/altunity/altunitytester/pages/get-started.html#)